# Are there any other ways of compiling c code that uses R api?

Tags: c, api, r

So far the only way I found is by making the shared object for a function that is written in e.g. myfile.c:

```
R CMD SHLIB myfile.c
```

and then testing in RGui using a script.

I want to code on Windows and i would like an easier way for compiling c code that uses R api calls, preferably using an IDE like Netbeans or Visual Studio. Is this possible ?

EDIT

Install Netbeans C\C++

Install R

Install RTools - contains C\C++ compiler for Netbeans

copy include files from R\R-2.12.2\include folder to RTools\MinGW\include folder

copy dll files from R\R-2.12.2\bin\i386 to Rtools\MinGW\lib

Make Netbeans project C\C++ - will require to select compiler tools from RTools\MinGW folder

copy required dll files from R\R-2.12.2\bin\i386 to execution folder of Netbeans Project

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is.  Just *look* at the output generated by `R CMD SHLIB foo.c` which is clearly echoed and *copy* these settings into your preferred IDE.  It will work, and it will be less portable.

Nobody handcuffs you; but R using the *same* command on *all platforms* is actually a real *feature* and not a bug as you seem to suggest.

Comment: i didn't suggest it's a bug, it just isn't as easy to get to a hello world app using an IDE such as Netbeans.

Comment: You are doing it wrong by copying files.  Set variables in your IDE to point to the right locations.

Comment: made a variable PATH=D:\dllFolder using Project Properties > Run > Environment, removed dlls from run folder with no succes (dlls are not visible)

The application failed with exit code -1073741515 (0xc0000135). 
This could indicate that no required .dll was found in the PATH. 
Please try to start the following command from the command shell (cmd.exe). 
This may give some additional information.